# Issues outputting data fom PSPing

Tags: powershell

Im trying to script something to ping a custom RDP port on a server for 7 hours & then save the output to a log file but I appear to have been going round in circles all week.

Im trying to see if the port is going down at any point or suffering for high latency.

Im using PSPing (Sysinternals) to ping the port but there aren't any switches to output the results to a log file & when I write the results out to a log I end up with missing info. Can anyone help

Here's what I have

```
$Server = "SERVER01"
$PSPingEXE = "C:\TEMP\PSTools"
$LogPath = "C:\TEMP\Logs\"

# Change DIR to PSPing.exe location
Set-Location $PSPingEXE

# Create function
Function Ping-Host {
$TimeNow = Get-Date
Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow "$TimeNow"
.\psping64.exe "$Server":1234
}
#setup loop
$TimeStart = Get-Date
$TimeEnd = $timeStart.AddHours(7)
Do { 
$TimeNow = Get-Date
if ($TimeNow -le $TimeEnd) {
Ping-Host | Out-File -FilePath ($LogPath+$Server+".csv")
} else {
Write-Host "All done for today" -ForegroundColor Green
}
Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
}
Until ($TimeNow -ge $TimeEnd)
```

Unfortunately PSPing doesnt record date/times so Im trying to look this bit of code & add the time into it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the cmdlet `Test-NetConnection` instead of PSPing.
It would work like this:

```
Test-NetConnection -ComputerName 'SERVER01' -Port '1234'
```

Now this would return an object where you can see if the TCP Ping succeeded.
So you could do it like this to

```
Do {
    $tnc = Test-NetConnection -ComputerName $server -Port 1234
    If ($tnc.TcpTestSucceeded) {
        Write-Output "Successfull ping!"
    } Else {
        Write-Output "Unseccessfull :("
    }
} Until ($TimeNow -ge $TimeEnd)
```

This should work just fine :)
With the logging part you could do something like this

```
$date = Get-Date
$result = "Successfull ping"

$output = "[" + $date + "] " + $result
$output | Out-File -FilePath $FilePath -Append
```

This would give an output like this: `[10/06/2021 13:35:48] Successfull ping`

Pay attention to the -Append
Else it doesn't add to the file, it just overwrites it.
Hopefully this helps :)